# Line break in facebook share via javascript share popup

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog, popup, share

I know that this question has been asked over and over, but I will try to be a little more specific about the code I am using and about the error I am receiving

So what I am using right now is:

```
FB.ui({
     method: 'feed',
     link: 'x',
     picture: 'x',
     name: 'x',
     caption: 'x',
     description: 'TEXT THAT I WANT ON MULTIPLE LINES',
     actions: {"name":"x", "link":"x"}
  },
  function (response) {
      something..
  });
```

This generates a popup window.
If I use `<center></center>` for a line break (as I've read on all responses around here) it does break the lines in the popup, but if I hit share, on my feed and other users on their wall see it without the line break ..

P.S: I have also used: `\n`, `\r`, `<center></center>`, `&#10`, `&#x0A`, `\u000A`, `%0A` with no luck ...

Here is how it looks in the popup window
[image]

This is how it looks on my feed
[image]

Any suggestion are much appreciated